# Application API LEVEL 26 and Android 7?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development . I have a simple question. If the method was introduced in API LEVEL 26 , can it be run on a device that has Android 7 OS?

Comment: What did your search turn up? Please be aware that you’re supposed to search before asking a question here (every time).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [list of Android versions and API levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Overview).

As you can see, Android 7.0 has API level 24. So the method will not be available as it was introduced later.

If the method in question is a standard Java method, in particular a method from `java.time`, `java.nio.file` or`java.lang.invoke`, then it might be available through [API desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) independent from the API level.